# Generate sound frequency in windows - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, audio, beep

i need to generate a square wave sound in windows . I'm using this code :

```
System.console.beep(500,500)
```

But it don't works very well : It takes a bit to play the sound .
I have a 2.7 GHZ CPU , so i don't think my computer is slow .

Does someone know a library or another code to play frequencies in windows ?

Comment: [How to generate sound according to frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042630/how-to-generate-sounds-according-to-frequency) I guess this is what you're looking for.

Comment: unluckily no , i want to play a continue sound frequency without System.console.beep()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imports:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Media
```

Call:

```
FrequencyBeep(500, 500, 10000)
```

Sub:

```
Public Shared Sub FrequencyBeep(ByVal Amplitude As Integer, ByVal Frequency As Integer, ByVal Duration As Integer)
    Dim A As Double = ((Amplitude * (System.Math.Pow(2, 15))) / 1000) - 1
    Dim DeltaFT As Double = 2 * Math.PI * Frequency / 44100.0
    Dim Samples As Integer = 441 * Duration / 10
    Dim Bytes As Integer = Samples * 4

    Dim Hdr As Integer() = {1179011410, 36 + Bytes, 1163280727, 544501094, 16, 131073, 44100, 176400, 1048580, 1635017060, Bytes}

    Using MS As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(44 + Bytes)

        Using BW As BinaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(MS)

            For I As Integer = 0 To Hdr.Length - 1
                BW.Write(Hdr(I))
            Next

            For T As Integer = 0 To Samples - 1
                Dim Sample As Short = System.Convert.ToInt16(A * Math.Sin(DeltaFT * T))
                BW.Write(Sample)
                BW.Write(Sample)
            Next

            BW.Flush()
            MS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

            Using SP As SoundPlayer = New SoundPlayer(MS)
                SP.PlaySync()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: I have a problem whit this code : SoundPlayer is not defined

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Did you import System.Media?

Comment: oh yes i forgot to import System.Media , now it works . Thank you so much !