# Sound chords in C#?

Tags: c#, audio, synthesis

I've tried using Console.Beep() at low millisecond rates two play two frequencies 'at once', but the pause between beeps ruins it. I have tried researching it but I've found nothing, and don't know where to start, aside from DirectSound, which I'm looking in to. All I need is to make a program that plays two or more frequencies simultaneously out of one speaker, in C#.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you look at DirectSound, which has nice .NET bindings. You can use two (or more) `Buffer` objects and invoke their `Play` methods to play them simultaneously.

[This tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973091.aspx) shows how to implement a simple drum machine in C# by synthesising sounds on the fly. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at using MIDI. [This example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MIDIToolkit.aspx) should get you started. It uses a MIDI library that several people recommend highly.

Answer (score 0):

Console.Beep() is synchronous and does not return until the sound is finished.

Try Simple DirectMedia Layer ([SDL.net](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cs-sdl/index.php?title=Audio)).

Answer (score 0):

Here's some very simple sample code that will let you play a WAV or MIDI file.  This way you can write your code once then just maintain the wav or mid file if you want to make changes to the sound effect.

[Play Any Sound File - C#](http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet217151.html) ( Uses DirectX 9.0 for Managed Code )

Answer (score 0):

If you know the frequencies beforehand you can synthesize them into a wave file (audacity or another similar program) and then play the wave file with the [SoundPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx) class.

```
string path = /*path goes here*/;
player = new SoundPlayer(path);
player.Play();
```

If you need to synthesize them at runtime you would have to write the file by hand. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203890/creating-sine-or-square-wave-in-c) a SO question that you can reference to build the wave files.