# can we reserve a cpu core for an application?

Tags: c#, cpu-cores

i've a DLL to manage pysical and my app to lead my DLL and UI.

manage pysical is not a problem and it work nice. My UI is okay with somes buttons and both work good too. But when i'm adding a timer or another who needed refresh, i've a problem into the pysical management. i think i need to fix conflis of UI or cost of refresh UI or isolate UI.

my app is on realTime mode.

[How to reserve a core for one thread on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346692/how-to-reserve-a-core-for-one-thread-on-windows) is not realy my problem.

if i need to reserve a cpu core (just one) for my application without any other interact of windows process into this core. Can we do this ?

or can we change the windows default load balancing mode ?
("Actually OS is capable of load balancing your cores/processors" [How can I set processor affinity to a thread or a Task in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510593/how-can-i-set-processor-affinity-in-net))

or how can isolate correctly my UI?

Comment: What if there were such a feature and every app that started before yours had already used it? It's unclear why you would need this - what's the underlying requirement? If your threads are busy, Window will generally not boot them off the core they are running on unless there are no idle cores to schedule work on.

Comment: i want reserve a core to manage pysical interaction, not for UI, i just want to refresh timer in my UI but it's causes somes physical "bugs", without refresh timer, i don't have any problems

Comment: Typical [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem)

Comment: This is not normally something I would recommend, but have you tried increasing the priority on your background thread? In any case it sounds like something else is going on that causes those hick-ups that you hint at. You should boil it down to a reproducible test case, if you can.

Comment: ahah :p

my X problem is manage pysical, and my Y is to refresh UI, just that.

I search just a solution or why not a new solution with your remarks

Comment: my app is on realTime mode. i think i need to reduce or isolate refresh UI cost but i  don't know how, actually I've just a timer, and i refresh it in an other thread, sorry my english is not my strength

Comment: It depends what "update UI" involves.  If it's too much work, perhaps do it in steps?  It's hard to know how to respond based on the information you've given here.

Comment: actually my update UI dot a get to my dll by collect a float (coresponding to a time), i convert this float into timespan (this is my estimater time) and i've a stopwatch managed by UI (my actual time) and : lbTime.Text =  formatTime(actualTime.Elapsed) + " / " + formatTime(estimaterTimeSpan); this just one interrupt my pysical management i don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

if we can optimize load balancing for fx processor (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2646060)
can we stop automatic windows load balancing cpu ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe to change number of processor into windows information can force windows to run with one core (and other app) ? this is just a idea.

Comment: this is doesn't work, windows restore the correct cpu number after reloading

Answer (score 0):

during my research I came across this information : [when GC thread kicks in, worker threads will be suspended.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729075/infinite-looping-consumes-100-cpu)

how can i control GC ? or can i to have more control on this?

i love Q/R ;)
i've seen here how to control my [GC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc713687%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This improvement has increase performance a lot. But i want more

Answer (score -1):

Run this application in an virtual machine ? so you can set the required hardware for it and it wont interfere with other stuff ?

Comment: i can't use virtual machine, it's not enough reactive, i use physical interactions into us. and on a VM i'll be always windows problems