# Generate Sinus Tone for a 1 second Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, dtmf

I'm a beginner developer for windows phone 8.1. 
I must generate a tone that represents sinus for 1 sec. How can I make this? (I saw the guides in this forum only for playing a sound from a file but that is not of my purpose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using the [NAudio Project](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) will help you.
See [here](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2009/10/playback-of-sine-wave-in-naudio.html) how to play a sin wave.

Comment: Hello TheCoolFrood. I've tried to add Naudio to my project but it rejects saying that windows phone is not supported...

Comment: Maybe check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203890/creating-sine-or-square-wave-in-c-sharp/19772815#19772815